# How to apply CSS to first td of last tr

Tags: html, css, html-table

I  need to change the width of first td of last tr in a table in which the contents in tbody are dynamically added.

My code:

```
<table id="items">
<tr>
<th>SL.No.</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to set the column slno as 50px, I mean the width of first td of all three rows, also I need to set the width of first td of last row as 500 px. How can I do this?

I did like this:

```
#items tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
width:500px;
}
```

but its not working.

Please help.

Comment: Setting the width of any `td` will also set the width to the same `td` in other rows.

Comment: What does it means "not working" there? This code is okay, you work in CSS with first TD in last row. It´s table, so you set the width of all first TDs.

Comment: -1 for simply saying ***not working***.

Comment: what i mean by say not wroking is, i need to set the width of first td in last row only. But with my current code it is setting the width to all first td's in all rows.Thatz am saying my code is not working as i need.

Comment: In a HTML table, the column width is determined by a multi-step algrorithm as described in: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout  The column width is determined by the "widest" table cell and that width affects all the table cells in the column regardless of which row the widest table cell is located.  What you are asking for cannot be done because tables are not designed to work that way.

Comment: You have to break the table-layout : http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/M9dhf/ but then what the use of table ? **colspan is a good compromised**

Answer (score 2):

Use `colspan` if you want a cell with a superior width than other cells.

An example is available here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work for your problem.

```
tr:last-child>td:first-child {
width:500px;
```

}

Comment: This should be dynamically change the first td of last tr.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**css**

```
#items tr:last-child td:first-child{
    width:500px;
}

#items tr td:first-child{
    width:50px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UX7ba/4/)